# Block Internet Explorer in Adobe Flex

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I use a couple functions to read the browser information when running my app.

```
var appName:String = ExternalInterface.call( "function getAppName(){ return navigator.appName; }" ); 
var appVersion:String = ExternalInterface.call( "function getAppVersion(){ return navigator.appVersion; }" ); 
var userAgent:String = ExternalInterface.call( "function getUserAgent() { return navigator.userAgent; }" );
```

And this is the result (**Chrome**):

```
navigator.appName: Netscape
navigator.appVersion: 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
```

How can I "block" the app, so the users can't use IE when running it, only allowing FF, Chrome, Opera, etc...?

For example, bring an alert box, and freeze the app in the background, until the user re-runs it on another browser.

Thank you!

> P.S.: I am kinda new to StackOverflow, so if my post isn't in the best
>   shape, please let me know!

Comment: After getting the user agent, you have just to verify if it's IE an do what you want to do ...

Comment: btw you can reduce your external interface call to just this ExternalInterface.call("navigator.userAgent"); There is no need to wrap it in its own function.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user agent contains the string "msie". If it does show the alert.

```
if (userAgent.contains("msie")) {
  Alert.show("nope");
} else {
  //carry on
}
```